# How to handle asyncTask and pause-button

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I am using asyncTasks for setting different layouts and to play sounds. Now I created a button to stop the sound and resume it. BUt there is a problem now with the asyncTask. I click on the pause-button and it pause, but when the asyncTask is called, it change to the next layout and play the next sound!

Thats the method to start the other methods by using asyncTasks:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   Crunch();
   handler =  new Handler();
   myRunnable = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
    UnterarmLiegestütz1();
     }
   };
   handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,wdh12);       
   myRunnable2 = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        Liegestützen1();
     }
   };
   handler.postDelayed(myRunnable2,2* wdh12);
}
```

My pause button:

```
 public void verlaufKlick(View view) {
    if (uebung.isPlaying()) {
      uebung.pause();
    } 
    else {
      uebung.start();
    }   
 }
```

The methods called by asncTask:

```
 public void Crunch() {
     setContentView(R.layout.crunch);
     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
     btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     uebung = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.crunch12);
     uebung.start();
 }

 public void UnterarmLiegestütz1(){
     setContentView(R.layout.liegestuetz);
     uebung = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ualiegestuetz20);
     uebung.start();
     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
     btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
 }
```

Liegestützen 1

```
 public void Liegestützen1() {
     setContentView(R.layout.liegestuetzen);
     uebung = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.frauenliege);
        uebung.start();
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crunch is not called by an asynctask, its directly under the onClick event. You should check android's asynctask documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: That doesn`t matter for my problem!

Comment: what I dont understand in the code is that in the onClick method you call crunch and UnterarmLiegestütz1, but both methods change the contentView and start a sound? Basically its doing the samething twice just with different sounds

Comment: That's right. I click the button and these exercises should start one by one.

Comment: Maybe try putting the runable in a thread and check if last thread is alive before starting next one?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

Thread thread = new Thread(Runnable runnable);
 Start it with thread.start();
then before starting other thread check if thread.isAlive()

Comment: I changed my whole code now ;) Now I am using public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) to check, if the sound is ready, if ready than change to next layout and play next sound.